# Completely reject a GET event in abap

Tags: abap

I would like to know how many times the [`GET`](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapget-.htm) event would happen without actually calling it (or calling it only one time).

By now, I know how to get the total number of iterations: `lines( (ldb_include)node_table[] )` , but this only works if the `GET` has been called, and if the `GET` has been called, it will iterate through node_table and if it has 8798237 entries, they all will be `PUT`, but as I already have the number of iterations (that's all I need), I don't want to have all the values put.

I can leave the `GET` by using [`REJECT`](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapreject.htm), but it will only go to the next iteration... currently, I don't know how to completely quit the GET.

I've tried using [`STOP`](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapstop.htm), but it raises the event of `end-of-selection` immediately, which is not the idea...

```
at selection-screen output.
  "process the selection screen

start-of-selection.
  get <node_tab>
    "lv_total = lines( (ldb_include)node_table[] )
    "some sort of REJECT to all get events
  "continue processing the rest of the code, using the lv_total

end-of-selection.
  "display the output
```

I can achieve it using a flag like

```
if first execution = abap_true. "process it
else reject <node_tab>.
```

But it would, in all cases, iterate through all the GET events, against the idea. I would like to understand if there is a smarter (possibly more elegant) to iterate only the first GET, and skip all the others.

Comment: Am I reading correctly that you're using a logical database, but only want to pull the first record that matches the selection criteria?  Wouldn't it be easier to just write your own select statement using select single or select up to 1 rows instead?

Comment: indeed, but Id like to have the difference between how many iterations the LDB would do and how many the optimized select would, and the only way to get the amount of the GET is by using the statement GET, since it triggers the LDB to fill its internal table. So what would happen is that the user would select the optmized select, but I'd have to call the GET anyways to get how many lines the LDB has in its internal table and compare it with how many lines my select returned...

Comment: either that or I copy and paste the LDB select inside my code, so I can always do both, but the LDB performs different selects depending on the selection screen fields used... you see, the whole point is to get how many times the LDB would process, but I think you can't do it without actually calling the GET, and if you call the GET, you will have to go through all the values it will bring... that's what I believe, at least.

Comment: wait a minute, I'll rewrite the question, I wasn't clear enough

Comment: I'm still struggling with why you're bothering with an LDB in the first place.  I've yet to see a good use of one outside of the HR module in a modern(ish) context, and the only reason to use that one is because it's got the authorizations baked in.

Comment: that exactly the case haha! I'm using an HR LDB, the only reason why I use it is due to the authority checks and to have the total number of possible selections. unfortunately, it seems I cannot replicate it inside my report without literaly copying and pasting the LDB logic

Comment: So you're trying to get a count of records that the LDB would find if you allowed it to run?  Is that right?

Comment: hello, Bryan, thats exactly right!

Comment: I don't think there is a great way to do this.  Either you have to clone the LDB (which I wouldn't do) or you have to write a custom select statement and do your best to get the authorizations right, or you just have to run the LDB through the events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's like saying there's a database view with joined tables, but one table is not needed, how to make the program read the view but tell the database not read one table...

Impossible!

The only solution is to copy and adapt the [Logical Database](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenldb.htm). As simple as that.

And, of course, logical databases are obsolete for a long time, so prefer using a database join, or anything else better.